# Eclipse Back/Forward navigation using mouse buttons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mouse

There is an addin for Visual Studio called [MouseNavi](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MouseNavi.aspx) that allows you to use mouse thumb buttons to navigate your history.

Does a similar extension exist for Eclipse?

Comment: While xMouseButtonControl is great there is another solution I found for owners of logitech mice w/ the SetPoint software installed. SetPoint allows you to define application specific action for all of you mouse button (essentially the same thing that xMouseButtonControl does -- but many people may have the setpoint software already installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any Eclipse plugin that does this, but assuming you're using Windows:

This one should enable you to do what you want: http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

With that tool you can assign each mouse button a sequence of keys (Alt+Left for example) and because it can be made application specific it won't interfere with other programs where you don't want that mapping.

Comment: This works if you map the thumb buttons to {ALT}{LEFT} and {ALT}{RIGHT}.

Comment: Thanks! Btw. you have to add an application, (which should be running) and in the default layer of the eclipse profile you can change the button to Simulated Keys using the above buttons. NO SPACE between ALT and left/right.

Comment: For linux if found a way by remapping the mouse button to Alt+Left. Fortunately this combination is also history back in firefox. Follow this great guide https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/11/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard.html and insert for example `"xdotool key 'Alt_L+Left'"
       b:8
` to the config.

Comment: Unbelievable that eclipse still hasn't included this feature request from **2003** so you don't have to rely on 3rd party software https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47099

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Left and Alt+Right to navigate through the latest opened editors.
Also, Alt+L to open up the shortcuts popup, so you can see what's available.

No real mouse navigation control though (not that I know of... at least). Although, should not be very difficult to create one and attach it to the same handlers that deal with the navigation commands.

Answer (score 0):

^Q takes you to last edited location. You can cycle using it. No mouse bindings.