# How can I map the ctrl click functionality in Eclipse to a middle mouse click?

Tags: eclipse, hyperlink, hotkeys

I want to switch the ctrl click functionality in Eclipse to be triggered by a middle mouse click. I saw a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387450/disable-eclipse-ctrl-click) about how to disable the ctrl click functionality; I want to preserve it but give it a different or additional hot key.

Comment: I think its not possible  because i think two actions are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse apparently [can](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47099) [not](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=235152) bind commands to mouse buttons.

You could work around that limitation by using a separate program that allows you to define application specific actions for your mouse buttons, eg. [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm), [Logitech SetPoint](https://www.google.com/search?q=logitech%20SetPoint) (both via [SO: Eclipse Back/Forward navigation using mouse buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902219/eclipse-back-forward-navigation-using-mouse-buttons)), or similar applications.

Or you switch to [an IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) [that allows mapping mouse buttons](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47099#c36) (and [much more](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/)).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can not bind it.

But you can bind it from the settings.

Try this link :

If you are using microsoft mouse.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/269054/customize-program-specific-mouse-settings-on-your-mac

Also there are many 3rd party apps which can bind your requirement.